# How an I debug connecting my Keycloak to LinkedIn

Tags: keycloak, linkedin-api

Using Keycloak's Admin UI I added LinkedIn as an identity provider to a realm.

I then went to my LinkedIn developer page and created an app there. I copied/pasted client id and client secret back to Keycloak. Then I copied Keycloak's *Redirect URI* and pasted it in the app settings on LinkedIn.

However, when I try to login using LinkedIn, I see this message:

> Bummer, something went wrong.
> In five seconds, you will be redirected to: accounts.example.tld

I'm stuck at this point. How should I debug this?